# Disable auto-centering after info bubble click -- HERE.com javascript api

Tags: javascript, here-api

In the info bubbles demo, whenever you click on an info bubble, the map centers at that position. Is there a way to disable that behavior? I would like to click on the info bubbles and have the bubble appear without altering the current map center position. Thanks.

Comment: Which demo? At least at https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/infoBubbles/open-infobubble nothing will be centered

Comment: I think it was the same demo. It's not doing the centering right now. I'm puzzled. Although I should still try it with the same computer as last time.. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Google Maps API V3 and you already know the latitude, longitude of your map center then you can use the center_changed event to your map object like this.

```
map.addListener('center_changed', function () {
   map.setCenter(mapCenter);//place your latitude and longitude of map center here
}
```

I'm afraid but this gives some error on the console of your browser.

Comment: Is this a working answer, or does it produce errors?